# Hide output of cmd command inside powershell

Tags: powershell

When set up of remote PowerShell session is impossible for me I'm using the `psexec` tool for launching scripts remotely. I'm asking for correct exit code of `psexec` in loop.
Syntax of `psexec` which I'm using is this:

```
./psexec.exe \\$Hostname -u $Username -p $Password -i ("c:\something.bat")
```

Is there any possibility to hide output in PowerShell console of `psexec` in each loop? I would like to see only the last success one.

I tried Out-Null, calling with `[void]` or `$null` redirection, but it seems as this is cmd command this don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `[void]` accelerator, like so: `[void] ./psexec.exe` `` `$hostname... ``